# Not able to parameterize LIMIT and OFFSET in sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Why following code is giving syntax error "**sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error**"

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('data.db')

cursor = connection.cursor()

table = "device_store"
uuid = "bbebe39e-fe2e-4817-b022-a3ef13bd6283"
page = 1
POSTS_PER_PAGE = 10
query = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE uuid=? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?"
result = cursor.execute(query, (table, uuid, POSTS_PER_PAGE, 0))
rows = result.fetchall()
connection.close()
print("==>> Printing rows <<==")
print(rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the placeholder in  `FROM ?`, not the others. Table names can't be passed as parameters, they have to be hardcoded in the statement.

Comment: Hi, I can pass table name as a parameter in other queries. I'm seeing this error only after adding "LIMIT" & "OFFSET" options to the query.

Comment: @ios_mxe  I'd like to see a query that does let you use a table name as a parameter, because that's not how sqlite (Or any RDMS I'm familiar with) works. It needs to know the table names when the statement is compiled to internal bytecode, they can't be given when the prepared statement is executed. Same with column names.

Comment: @classmethod
    def find_by_uuid_distinct(cls, uuid, table):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = "SELECT DISTINCT domain FROM ? WHERE uuid=?"
        result = cursor.execute(query, (table, uuid))
        rows = result.fetchall()
        connection.close()
        print("==>> Printing rows for unique domain names <<==")
        print(rows)
        print(rows[0][0])
        return rows

Comment: In classmethod shown above, I'm passing in "table" as a parameter which is then substituted in sqlite query. This part of code is working fine.

Comment: Never mind Shawn! This snippet is a dead code lying around written by a colleague earlier. I used it and it has caused collateral.